# Object equality comparison typescript. Cannot apply Object properties to generic type

Tags: typescript, generics, equals

Trying to obtain understand better object comparison in Javascript, along with the property access with typescript, I tried to make for my class an Equal comparer from this starting point.

[TypeScript : Object Equality Comparison (Object Equals Object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46705216/typescript-object-equality-comparison-object-equals-object)

I know this can be done with stringify and loadash, but I find it interesting to dig into the object properties to apply logic.

This is the code to compare the two objects (from the link above):

```
private equals<T>(x: T, y: T): boolean {
    if (x === y) {
      return true; // if both x and y are null or undefined and exactly the same
    }
    if (!(x instanceof Object) || !(y instanceof Object)) {
      return false; // if they are not strictly equal, they both need to be Objects
    }
    if (x.constructor !== y.constructor) {
      // they must have the exact same prototype chain, the closest we can do is
      // test their constructor.
      return false;
    }
    for (const p in x) {
      if (!x.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        continue; // other properties were tested using x.constructor === y.constructor
      }
      if (!y.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        return false; // allows to compare x[ p ] and y[ p ] when set to undefined
      }
      if (x[p] === y[p]) {
        continue; // if they have the same strict value or identity then they are equal
      }
      if (typeof (x[p]) !== 'object') {
        return false; // Numbers, Strings, Functions, Booleans must be strictly equal
      }
      if (!this.equals(x[p], y[p])) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    for (const p in y) {
      if (y.hasOwnProperty(p) && !x.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

My problem is that I cannot access the Object properties constructor and hasOwnProperty. I obtain the error:

> Property 'hasOwnProperty' does not exist on type 'Vec3'.ts(2339).

I tried to implement the interface:

```
interface ObjectPropertiesHandlable {
  constructor: void;
  hasOwnProperty: void;
}
```

So that in the declaration `private equals<T extends ObjectPropertiesHandlable>(x: T, y: T): boolean {` I can fix the compilation error.

But if so, the arguments here won't fit:

```
    if (!this.equals(x[p], y[p])) {
        return false;
      }
```

As p is of type `const p: Extract<keyof Vec3, string>` (by the typescript intellisense onHover)

If I substitute the generic by my class type (it's a `Vec3` class, however not relevant) although it has a constructor, I keep having the errors:

> Property 'hasOwnProperty' does not exist on type 'Vec3'.ts(2339).

> Property 'constructor' does not exist on type 'Vec3'.ts(2339).

If I apply an interface to avoid the object property error, I obtain this error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to make it work, try next code :

```js
type Indexed = {
  [index: string]: unknown
}

const equals = <T extends Indexed>(x: T, y: T) => {
  // ... your code
}
```

You just should asure TS that your arguments are actually objects.

Please take a look on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308370/what-is-the-syntax-for-typescript-arrow-functions-with-generics)

**UPDATE**
Try:

```js
type Indexed = {
  [index: string]: Indexed
}
```

I ti a little bit dirty, but if you will explain me what are U trying to achieve maybe I will provide better solution

Comment: If the generic extends the type then I obtain an error in another part of the code, because arguments type dont fit (equals seems to be called recursively and the properties are passed as strings inside the method). It was explained but I added a screenshot to clarify. Many thanks

Comment: Like I understood, T type can be any value ? I mean: array, string, number, function etc ... ?

Comment: In my case It is a class of mine. Holding 3 numbers and a Float32 array. But as far as I understand from the question where I got the code, could be any type (as far as its an object I think)

Comment: So x and y are objects with 3 properties?

Comment: x and y are instances of a class

Comment: So you dont need to use generic T at all.

Comment: the class has 5 properties, 3 are numbers, and array32 and a boolean. I can post the code if that helps, I dont think so though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221058/discussion-between-captain-yossarian-and-rustybucketbay).